# Take every second row from existing dataframe and arrange them in to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series which looks like this :

| min | Volume every minute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.3 |
| 3 | 0.4 |
| . | . |
| 1440 | 0.8 |
| 1441 | 0.5 |
| . | . |
| 4018 | 0.6 |
| . | . |
| 252000 | 0.7 |
| 252001 | 0.9 |

I have to arrange this in to new dataframe in such a way that **min** column should have every 1441st value. Also created columns are something like this :

**1_1, 1_2,1_3, ...1_1339, 1_1440** -- Entries every min (1440 entries from 1 | 1440 entries from 1441 | 1440 entries from 2881 .... )
**3_1, 3_2,3_3, ...3_1339, 3_1440** -- Entries every 3 min (1440 entries from 1 | 1440 entries from 1441 | 1440 entries from 2881 .... )
**5_1, 5_2,5_3, ...5_1339, 5_1440** -- Entries every 5 min (1440 entries from 1 | 1440 entries from 1441 | 1440 entries from 2881 .... )

| min | 1_1 | .. | 1_1440 | 3_1 | .. | 3_1440 | .. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | . | 0.8 | 0.2 | . | 0.6 |  |
| 1441 | 0.5 | . | val at 2880 min | 0.5 | . | val at 5458 min |  |
| . | . | . | . | . | . | . |  |
| . | . | . | . | . | . | . |  |
| 252001 | 0.9 | NaN | NaN | NaN | . | NaN |  |

i know i might have to use `DataFrame.pivot_table` with `DataFrame.add_prefix` but little clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
dfs = []
for m in (1, 3, 5):
    dfs.append(
        pd.concat(
            (df.iloc[n:n+1440*m:m, 1].reset_index(drop=True).rename(n + 1)
             for n in range(0, df.shape[0], 1440)),
            axis=1
        ).rename(lambda n: f"{m}_{n+1}", axis=0).rename_axis("min", axis=1)
    )
df_result = pd.concat(dfs).T.reset_index()
```

- For each `m` (the step width) take slices of the `Volume ...` column: Start at every 1440th row and then slice the remainig in `m`-steps, at most 1440 times.
- Take the slices and put them as columns in dataframe (via `pd.concat`) and do some renaming.
- Concatenate all the 3 blocks, transpose the result, and reset the index to get the `min` column back.

In case you have a series `ser` instead of a dataframe `df` (as stated in the question) you should replace `df.iloc[n:n+1440*m:m, 1]` with `ser.iloc[n:n+1440*m:m]`.

Comment: with big samples getting performance issues

Comment: thanks for the help! The thing is that i made the question fairly simple but in reality the min column contain 25200 entries and for the final output instead of every second entry ; min column should have every 1440th value.  Also created columns are something like this -- for 1 min entries (total 1440 ): 1_1, 1_2,1_3, ...1_1339, 1_1440 for every 3 min entries (total 1440): 3_1, 3_4,3_7, ...3_4015, 3_4018, for every 5 min entries (total 1440): 5_1, 5_6,5_11, ...3_6691, 3_6696.

Comment: i hope now understanding is clear. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @prem I think I finally got it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Timus. Imagine for such question some one just gave a negative rating to it.